# Data validation not working in view (DataAnnotations)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I'm having trouble getting data validation working in my view.
I believe 'AssetName' should show an error message if a user tabs into the textbox and doesn't put any data in but no message is shown when the textbox loses focus.

Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ACore.Models
{
    public class AssetForm
    {
        [Required]
        public string AssetName { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        [UIHint("StatesEditor")]
        public State State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "TEST")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Seg3Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@model ACore.Models.AssetForm

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAsset" }))
{
    <div class="tempStyle">
        <div class="editor-label fl">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssetName)*@
            Asset Name:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tempStyle">
        <div class="editor-label">
            Address 1:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Section of Web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

I ended up adding the code below but it appears that the DataAnnotations in my class have no bearing on the validation. I would prefer to control the validation through DataAnnotations:

```
// Validate the Maintenance and Office percentages.
    var validator = $("#frmAsset").validate({
        rules: {
            AssetName: {
                required: true
            },
            Seg3Code: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 3
            }
        },
        messages: {
            AssetName: "&nbsp;&#10006;&nbsp;Required",
            Seg3Code: "&nbsp;&#10006;&nbsp;Required"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Asset/Create",
                data: {

                },
                //data: $("form").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);

                    // Close popup window
                    var window = $('#AssetEditorPopUp').data("kendoWindow");
                    window.close();

                    // Refresh grid to show changes
                    $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                },

                error: function () {
                    alert("There was an error editing the asset.");
                }
            });

            return false; // to block page redirect since you're using ajax
        }
```

Comment: have you got the Jquery libraries referred in your view? Also i dont think the Required Attribute is immediately validated.If the field is empty then ModelState goes to error only during a post

Comment: I have my jquery libraries added in my _Layout.cshtml. I've also tried adding jquery.min.js and jquery.validate.js to the page with no luck.

Comment: The message should appear when user tabs out of empty text box, that is required, rather than tabbing into it. Or is it you just mis-phrased your sentence?

Comment: Mis-phrased indeed. When I tab out of the empty textbox I get no message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you BeginForm there is no posting action that is causing Submit and hence call validation. This is required unless you have some Javascript code that validate on tab-out.

In your using code block add

```
<input type="submit" value="textOnSubmitButton" />
```

and provide action and controller in BeginForm function to handle action on posting of form in the controller.
Add this in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult theAction(){
    return View();
}
```

You will get error message on click of the submit button